# How to use hook alter form in module to register a user and also save some data in another table?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

have a general idea on how to use hook alter to modify the feel of the registration form .

However the challenge I have is to not only have the user register, but to save some extra data into another table and then redirect user to a new page.

How would I get about doing that? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Again, it'd be easier to plan what you're trying to do and take advantage of common solutions. I suspect what you're after is the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module.

Comment: Having see your other question, ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017759/drupal-studs-help-me-with-my-form-alter-hook-i-am-almost-there ), you don't even need that. Just use Drupal's Profile module.

Answer (score 0):

add a custom function to your form, according to http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop for more info

please notice the login page and the login block are different forms, with different form ids for your hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `hook_user()`; when the first parameter is `'register'`, the registration form is being presented to a user, and the module can change it by adding new form fields (the module needs to return them to Drupal).