# Drupal Studs help me with my form_alter hook ( I am almost there)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

So I think I am almost there conceptually but need some missing pointers.

Objective is to add a few more fields to the normal user registration form, style it a little, then submit it with storing the extra fields in a table.

This is what I have so far. Can someone give me the final nudge and get me going. Please help me. Also how do I apply some minor styling like aligning the new form fields ?

Thank you so much !!!!!!!!!

```
  function module_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['school/registration'] = array(
      'title' => 'Upgraded Registration Form',
      'page callback'    =>'module_school_register',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK

    );
```

return $items;
}//end of the function

function module_school_register(){
return drupal_get_form('form_school_register');
}//end of the function

function module_school_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{

dsm($form_id);

if ($form_id == 'user_registration_form')
   {
// modify the "#submit" form property by prepending another submit handler array
$form['#submit'] = array_merge(
      array('_module_registration_submit' => array()),
      $form['#submit']
    );

}
}

function _module_registration_submit($form_id, $form_values) {
  // store extra data in different table
}

function module_registration_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
$error=0;
   //Validation stuff here, set $error to true if something went wrong, or however u want to do this.  Completely up to u in how u set errors.
   if ($error)
   {
      form_set_error('new_field_name', 'AHH SOMETHING WRONG!');
   }
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014069/how-to-use-hook-alter-form-in-module-to-register-a-user-and-also-save-some-data-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at content profile module before rolling your own solution.

You define your a custom content type (node) for your school registration, add in you cck fields, and activate it as a content profile. On content profile settings, you then activate it on user registration form. Zero code !

Answer (score 1):

RedBen is right, [content profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) may be a better solution.

It seems like you're adding the second submit handler in a strange way - it's simply the name of a function, not an array. Have you checked that your submit handler is running?

Because the reference to the handler is a simple string, you just need to append it to the array using

`$form['#submit'][] = '_module_registration_submit'`

If you need it to run before the standard handler, use `array_unshift` to push it onto the beginning of the `#submit` array.